# IdentityServer3, Azure Active Directory External Provider, Message='Action returned 'System.Web.Http.Results.Unauthorized''

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-active-directory, identityserver3

I'm seeing strange behavior with IdentityServer3 and External Providers.  I'm hoping someone will be able to point out something obvious I've missed.

**Summary**

*First External Login request sets the browser waiting for the request to be returned and results in the errors below visible only through logging.  If I cancel the request in the browser and immediately click the button again, it works as intended, the browser is sent to the external login screen.*

---

**Configuration**

I've configured IDSrv3 according to some references and the documentation as well as I can ascertain, to leverage Azure Active Directory.

```
 var wsFedOptions = new WsFederationPluginOptions(options);
    wsFedOptions.Factory.Register(new Registration<IEnumerable<RelyingParty>>(RelyingParties.Get()));
    wsFedOptions.Factory.RelyingPartyService = new Registration<IRelyingPartyService>(typeof(InMemoryRelyingPartyService));
    app.UseWsFederationPlugin(wsFedOptions);



 var aad = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "AzureAd",
                Caption = "Azure AD",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = Settings.LogoutRedirect,
                Authority = Settings.AADAuthority,
                ClientId = Settings.AADClientId,
                RedirectUri = Settings.AADRedirectUrl
            };

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(aad);
```

On the Login View, I'm presented with the External Login button as captioned above (Azure AD), as expected.  The first time this button is clicked, the browser just sits waiting for the host...

In the logs I discovered the following errors.

```
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2017-04-05 08:28:09.708 -05:00 [Information] External login requested for provider: "AzureAd"
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2017-04-05 08:28:09.714 -05:00 [Information] Triggering challenge for external identity provider
LibLog Information: 0 : [2017-04-05T13:28:09.7176576Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.Action', Id=800000ad-0002-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Action returned 'System.Web.Http.Results.UnauthorizedResult'', Operation=ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync
LibLog Information: 0 : [2017-04-05T13:28:09.7206611Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.Action', Id=800000ad-0002-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Operation=ApiControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsync, Status=401 (Unauthorized)
LibLog Information: 0 : [2017-04-05T13:28:09.7216630Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Web.Http.Filters', Id=800000ad-0002-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Action filter for 'LoginExternal(String signin, String provider)'', Operation=NoCacheAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync, Status=401 (Unauthorized)
LibLog Information: 0 : [2017-04-05T13:28:09.7226640Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.Filters', Id=800000ad-0002-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Operation=NoCacheAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync, Status=401 (Unauthorized)
LibLog Information: 0 : [2017-04-05T13:28:09.7226640Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Web.Http.Filters', Id=800000ad-0002-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Action filter for 'LoginExternal(String signin, String provider)'', Operation=SecurityHeadersAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync, Status=401 (Unauthorized)
LibLog Information: 0 : [2017-04-05T13:28:09.7236655Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.Filters', Id=800000ad-0002-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Operation=SecurityHeadersAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync, Status=401 (Unauthorized)
LibLog Information: 0 : [2017-04-05T13:28:09.7246669Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.Controllers', Id=800000ad-0002-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Operation=AuthenticationController.ExecuteAsync, Status=401 (Unauthorized)
LibLog Information: 0 : [2017-04-05T13:28:09.7251836Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.MessageHandlers', Id=800000ad-0002-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Operation=PassiveAuthenticationMessageHandler.SendAsync, Status=401 (Unauthorized)
LibLog Information: 0 : [2017-04-05T13:28:09.7261856Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.MessageHandlers', Id=800000ad-0002-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Operation=DependencyScopeHandler.SendAsync, Status=401 (Unauthorized)
LibLog Information: 0 : [2017-04-05T13:28:09.7271879Z] Sending response, Status=401 (Unauthorized), Method=GET, Url=https://localhost:44396/identity/external?provider=AzureAd&signin=2d92dd18a6106c9b029eb8742d4117a1, Id=800000ad-0002-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Content-type='none', content-length=unknown'
```

The browser will continue waiting on localhost indefinitely.  **If I stop the request and immediately click the button again, everything works as intended.**

Comment: The error appears to be happening in IDSrv3 AuthenticatioinController.cs at line 330  Just prior context.Authentication.Challenget(authProp, provider) then this method immediately return Unauthorized();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem is related to the deadlock bug in the Katana OIDC MW. 
The workaround is to create a custom IConfigurationManager and fetch the metadata manually at startup.  Similar to the one proposed by Thinktecture.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Host.Configuration/Extensions/SyncConfigurationManager.cs

Substituting OpenIdConnectConfiguration

```
var manager = new SyncConfigurationManager(new ConfigurationManager < OpenIdConnectConfiguration > (Settings.AADAuthority + "/.well-known/openid-configuration"));
```

Then add the manager to the OpenIdAuthenticationOptions

```
    var aad = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationType = "AzureAd",
                    Caption = "Marquis Azure AD",
                    SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = Settings.LogoutRedirect,
                    Authority = Settings.AADAuthority,
                    ClientId = Settings.AADClientId,
                    RedirectUri = Settings.AADRedirectUrl,
                    ConfigurationManager = manager
                };
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` the code seems be correct. I am also using the code below to login the IdentityServer3 with Azure AD account and it works well for me:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.Trace()
            .CreateLogger();

        var users = new List<InMemoryUser>()
        {
            new InMemoryUser
            {
                Username="Jack", Password="Jack",
                Claims= new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim("name","Jack"),
                    new Claim("email","Jack@consoto.com"),
                    new Claim("role","Admin"),
                }
            }
        };

        var clients = new Client[]
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId="mvc",
                ClientName="MVC Demo Client",
                Flow=Flows.Implicit,
                RedirectUris=new List<string>
                {
                    "http://localhost:9000",
                    "http://localhost:1409/"
                },
                AllowedScopes=new List<string>
                {
                    "openid","email","profile","roles"
                }
            }
        };

        var scopes = new Scope[]
            {
                StandardScopes.OpenId,
                StandardScopes.ProfileAlwaysInclude,
                StandardScopes.EmailAlwaysInclude,
                new Scope
                {
                    Name="roles",
                    Claims=new List<ScopeClaim>
                    {
                        new ScopeClaim("role")
                    },
                    Type=ScopeType.Identity
                }
            };

        var factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory();
        factory.UseInMemoryClients(clients);
        factory.UseInMemoryScopes(scopes);
        factory.UseInMemoryUsers(users);

        var cert = LoadCertificate();

        app.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
        {
            SiteName = "NDC Demo",
            SigningCertificate = cert,
            Factory = factory,
            AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions
            {
                IdentityProviders = ConfigureAdditionalIdentityProviders,
                EnableAutoCallbackForFederatedSignout = true
            }
        });
    }

    public static void ConfigureAdditionalIdentityProviders(IAppBuilder app, string signInAsType)
    {
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "aad",
            Caption = "Azure AD",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,

            Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/04e14a2c-0e9b-42f8-8b22-3c4a2f1d8800",
            ClientId = "eca61fd9-f491-4f03-a622-90837bbc1711",
            RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44333/core/aadcb",
        });
    }

    static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate()
    {
        var baseFolder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        string certificatePath = $"{baseFolder}\\Certificates\\mycompanyname.pfx";
        return new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, "", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
    }
}
```

Then we can interact with IdentityServer3 with the request below:

`https://localhost:44333/connect/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=mvc&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9000&scope=openid+email+profile+roles&nonce=123`

Please let me whether it is helpful.

Comment: Nothing in your configuration that isn't already in mine, with the exception that I use login.windows.net/[tenantID].   Like I said, it works, but only if I cancel the first request.  I suspect IDSrv3 is the root of the problem here, Thanks for the effort.